# Set polygon.io incoming socket messages to redis in every 5 minutes and post to lambda using node js

Tags: node.js, lambda, websocket, redis

I am using polygon.io websocket for receiving stock trades. The logic is to store the incoming messages to redis , one message with expiry time 5 minutes. So that , as I am start receiving socket message , I used map function to process the messages and passed them to redis and checked whether currently the stock has any value in redis. If no, then set the value with 5minute expiry .At that time I need to post the value to lambda. Then after the expire time , need to set another incoming value. So the purpose is to post to lambda at every 5 minutes based on redis set value with expiry time. I have used following code to recieve socket message and passed them to redis function.

```
     ws.on('message', (data: string) => {
            let polygonMessage = JSON.parse(data)
            polygonMessage.map((msg: PolygonResponse) => {
                if (msg.ev === 'status') {
                    socketLog.info('Status Update:', msg.message)
                    return console.log('Status Update:', msg.message)
                }
                if ((msg.hasOwnProperty('sym')) && (msg.hasOwnProperty('p'))) {
                     redis.stockDetails(msg.sym, msg.p).then((res:any) => {

                        if (res == true) {
                            let currentDateTime = this.checkTime();
                            socketLog.info('Set to Redis :' + msg.sym + ': ' + msg.p + '  ,DateTime: ' + currentDateTime)
                            axios.post('https://********', {
                                    stock: msg.sym,
                                    price: msg.p
                                }).then((res: any) => {
                                    console.log(' statusCode : ' + res.status )
                                })
                                .catch((error: any) => {
                                    console.log('Lambda Error : ' + error)
                                })
                            
                        } else {
                            socketLog.info('delay :' + msg.sym + ': ' + msg.p)
                        }

                    })

                }
            })
        })
```

CheckTime Function

```
public checkTime() {
    const today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate());
    const date = (today.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + today.getDate() : today.getDate();
    const month = (today.getMonth() < 10) ? '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1) : today.getMonth() + 1;
    const currentDate = today.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    const hours = (today.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + today.getHours() : today.getHours();
    const minutes = (today.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + today.getMinutes() : today.getMinutes();
    const seconds = (today.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + today.getSeconds() : today.getSeconds();
    let currentdatetime: any = currentDate + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    return currentdatetime;
}
```

The redis function is as follows,

```
public async stockDetails(symbol: any, price: any) {
    const getAsync = promisify(this.client.get).bind(this.client);
    const setAsync = promisify(this.client.set).bind(this.client);
    const expireAsync = promisify(this.client.expire).bind(this.client);

    let getSymbol = await getAsync(symbol);
    console.log("getSymbol:" + getSymbol)
    if (getSymbol == null) {
        await setAsync(symbol, price)
        await expireAsync(symbol, 300)
        console.log("Get current value : " + getAsync(symbol))
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("set not empty")
        return false;
    }
}
```

My desired output is like this during every 5 minutes.

```
Set to Redis : AAPL  : 131, DateTime: 2021-02-19 10:10:10
Set to Redis : AAPL  : 132, DateTime: 2021-02-19 10:15:10
```

But now it is like,setting to redis in same minute itself

```
Set to Redis : AAPL  : 131, DateTime: 2021-02-19 10:10:10
Set to Redis : AAPL  : 132, DateTime: 2021-02-19 10:10:10
```

This will result in multiple lambda post at same time. I need to post to lambda only once in every 5 minute.

Comment: Can you please add the implementation of `this.checkTime`?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman I have updated the question with this.checkTime